# Ribbon Workbench adding PrimaryControl param breaks form

Tags: javascript, dynamics-365, crm-ribbon-workbench

When adding a Crm Parameter to a Custom JavaScript Action in Ribbon Workbench, I get the following when in the Unified Interface. Works in the legacy client.

[image]

Just adding PrimaryControl as a Crm Parameter to my JavaScript action.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was to add both the CommandProperties and PrimaryControl as Crm Parameters to the JavaScript action using the following order:

[image]

And making sure to pass there parameters into the function.

```
function HandleSyncTask(commandProperties, primaryControl) { /* more logic */ }
```